# Matplotlib, 3D logaxis, incomplete figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am playing with matplotlib, I would like to have a 3d figure with logarithmic axis. I was trying some code, like the one below, but I can only see part of the figure at a time, if I try to move it, I can see other parts, but, not complete.

Does anyone have any idea how to make a 3D plot with log axis?

I can see the 3D image if the axis are linear, but as soon as I change to "log", I can only see part of it.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
data=np.array([[1,10,100],[10,1,1],[2,20,82]])
fig=plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
#ax.set_xlim3d(0.1,15)
#ax.set_ylim3d(0.1,15)
#ax.set_zlim3d(0.1,15)
ax.xaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.zaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2])
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by just seeing a part of the plot at a time? Only one dot out of three dots? Get rid of the `set_(you_name_it)lim3d` should give you all the dots.

Comment: also see: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209

Comment: it is like if the plot were bigger than the canvas, unfortunately I cannot attach figures :(

Answer (score 1):

I updated matplotlib to 1.3.1, and now I can see the full figure. Now, I think the axis are not in a log scale. I made a plot in  matplotlib [image: matplotlib] and the same plot with gnuplot [image: gnuplot], and it can be seen that the distances between every power of 10, are comlpetely different.

Answer (score -1):

The [3d scatter plot](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) requires x,y,z arguments: if you are trying to plot z data[:,2] (3 points) function of x data[:,0] and y data[:,1], you will see 3 points when the xlim3d,ylim3d,zlim3d are set correctly. This can be done by setting the them to min() and max() of each x,y,z value:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.array([[1,10,100],[10,1,1],[2,20,82]])
fig=plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.set_xlim3d(data[:,0].min(),data[:,0].max())
ax.set_ylim3d(data[:,1].min(),data[:,1].max())
ax.set_zlim3d(data[:,2].min(),data[:,2].max())
ax.xaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.zaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now if you wanted to plot the data array in 3d manner, 9 points in this case, you would need the respective x and y axis. This can be done with np.meshgrid(). In this example I have set x, y equidistant [1,2,3].

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.array([[1,10,100],[10,1,1],[2,20,82]])
datax=np.array([1,2,3])
datay=np.array([1,2,3])
dataxM,datayM = np.meshgrid(datax, datay)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.set_xlim3d(datax.min(),datax.max())
ax.set_ylim3d(datay.min(),datay.max())
ax.set_zlim3d(data.min(),data.max())
ax.xaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.zaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.scatter(dataxM,datayM,data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see that It can be done, I guess, the problem is with my computer, I am running it in debian, I wanted to upload a figure, but since I am new, my reputation doesn't allow me still to post images.

Comment: which version of python are you using?, I'm running python 2.7.3 in debian wheezy. Maybe there's a problem with my version.

Comment: nowhere in this answer do you use logarithmic axes.  this is not a true answer to the question.